# Origin of the definitions of 16 types of discrete normalized/non-normalized Sine and Cosine transforms

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, dft

I am a Ph.D in pure math. In the literature of signal processing, I observe that 16 types of discrete normalized/non-normalized Sine and Cosine transforms are being extensively studied. They have some particular formulas.

What is the origin of their definitions? Why are only these special cases considered and named? (since with changes in the parameters, one may find some other types).

Comment: Hey 16 is more transforms that I'm aware of. What literature have you been reading and what are these? Generally, you can assume utility to be a good motivation: for example, the Fourier transform decomposes a large class of functions into an orthogonal base of eigenfunctions of any linear time-invariant system. That is very directly useful if you want to send a signal through such a system. The Laplace transform is similar, but more useful for another class of functions, and had very useful properties when it comes to derivatives and anti-derivatives, rendering it great for control systems.

Comment: So the problem here will become that you're asking us about the utility of 16 things (assuming you'll list them explicitly; no use speculating about which you mean), and that might easily exceed the scope of what someone could reasonably write in an answer here.

Comment: @  Marcus Müller, Thanks. Yes, the utility of these particular discrete transforms is what I want to know about. Moreover, any of these  transformations is probably based (considered) on some special  motivation (or task!) These are my concerns.

Comment: Well again, 16 is a lot but you named zero of them explicitly. We can't read minds, please edit your question to explicitly name them. And I'd still say asking about 16 utilities requires us to write a book chapter, not a stack exchange answer, and would be too broad. It's best if you restrict yourself to one or maybe a pair that is related. (You can always ask new questions later on)

Comment: Here is a good starting point for the DCT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform. How about you expand your question from that?

Comment: "the utility of these particular discrete transforms" If you can say you're interested in them, **you can list them out**.  Please _edit your question_ with the list.